# How to use HadoopJarStepConfig.StepProperties?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, emr, amazon-emr

AWS docs state that this property is "A list of Java properties that are set when the job flow step runs. You can use these properties to pass key-value pairs to your main function in the JAR file."

But there is no explanation (at least, I failed to find any) how exactly they are passed, and how to properly access said collection of key-value pairs on a main function side.

Quick check proved that they aren't passed via environment nor command line arguments. Could be some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, seems that this map goes to Java system properties and is accessible from main function side via System.getProperties() call, but there are some non-obvious implications.

First thing to keep in the mind, that internally they are set via environment variable HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS as -Dkey=value switches. But EMR does not bother itself to properly escape keys nor values by shell rules.

Also, it does not report any syntax errors if there are properties with non-printable characters, just omits setting them altogether. And it plays even worse with special shell characters like * ? ( ) \ and such — it'll fail the task execution without a proper explanation, and the log records will vaguely point only to obscure syntax errors in some eval() call deeply inside of EMR internal shell script wrappers.

Please be aware about that behaviour.

Properties must be shell-escaped, and in some cases even doubly shell-escaped.